# Search based on a metadata property in Marklogic Java Api

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have added metadata property in the document as

```
 metadata.getProperties().put("systemDate" , date);
```

and added it in collection "/sample"
I want to retrieve all documents from this collection in descending order based on systemDate

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590730/marklogic-java-api-get-search-results-sorted and http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2010-August/006123.html

Comment: Once you're on MarkLogic 9 you could use metadata values instead of properties or a document element since metadata values are in the document fragment.  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_54096

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MarkLogic, java API. Get search results sorted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590730/marklogic-java-api-get-search-results-sorted)

Comment: Properties are stored in a different fragment, making it a bit more difficult to sort on them using REST and Java api. Hidden metadata fields, new in MarkLogic 9, are (as mentioned by Sam) tied to the document fragment, and should prove easy to use, and perform better too. See Sam's comment for a link with more details..